# Does using the statement "find" cause my O(n) notation to go to O(n^2) notation in C++?

Tags: c++, time, big-o

Recently, I've tried to start competitive programming and got quite curious about the "find" statement. We know that the find statement, just like in the example below, can replace a second for loop. By replacing it, I was curious if the time notation still stay the same, O(n^2) or does it decrease to O(n)? Thank you for your answer.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < string.size(); i++) {
        auto it = find(string.begin(), string.end(), 3);
        int index = it - string.begin();
        vector[i] = string[index - 1];
    }


    int d;
    for(int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++) {
        for(int u = 0; u < 26; u++) {
            if(u == string[i]) {
                d = u;
            }
        }
        vector[i] = string[d - 1];
    }
```

I was looking into this problem. However, I'm still confused. Sorry if this is a redundant question.

Comment: How does `find()` itself work? What kinds of algorithms could it use? How would that affect the function’s running time? Have you tried benchmarking both versions with varying input sizes to see what kind of complexity class each version appears to show?

Comment: It's stlll `O(n^2)`.  One way to know that `find` (which is a function call not a statement) is itself `O(n)` is to consider what it has to do in the worst case:  In the worse case it has to look at every character of its argument string.  So that makes find `O(n)` by itself.  There's a loop there _hidden inside_ the function - you've still got nested loops.  (It could very well be faster than a loop you'd write yourself, because the library authors are very careful/crafty/clever people.)

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of writing the first loop. Nothing in the outer loop body depends on the dummy variable `i`, except for the assignment of a result into `vector[i]`.   The loop appears to calculate exactly the same result N times, and assigns that result to successive positions of `vector`.  This can be changed to just calculating the result once (one call to `find`, et cetera), and then writing a loop which duplicates the result into those `vector` positions.

Comment: If that were the case, then the `find` would have to take constant time – that is, its time does not depend on the length of the input. It is reasonably obvious that this is impossible. If the input were structured (e.g. sorted) then a tailored `find` (e.g. a binary search) could do better than O(n), but not in the general case.

Comment: *"tried to start competitive programming and"* -- this is not directly relevant to your question, and given the reputation of competitive programming, your question might look 10x better if you dropped this part (keeping the rest of the sentence it is in).

Comment: One way to answer your question is to look at some documentation for the algorithm. Using cppreference for [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), check the complexity section. Given a length N to search, it performs at most N comparisons. It's linear or O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::find` works on input/forward iterators. As such, it cannot move backwards, and it cannot perform random access. It's equivalent to the straightforward `for` loop, aside from working on iterators, rather than indices.

There are cases where a `find` member function *can* improve performance, but it's a member function of specific containers which can optimize the search (e.g. `set` and `map`, as well as `unordered_*` and `multi*` variants thereof), there's no top-level function operating on iterators that can do it.